# Xamarin Visual Studio Mac: what and where is the "runtime" node?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I'm getting an error in Visual Studio Mac that includes this text:

```
[blah blah blah...] add the following binding redirects to the "runtime" node in 
the application configuration file: [...blah blah blah]
```

...can anyone tell me what the "runtime" node is, and where the application configuration file is?

Comment: post full error stack here ??

Comment: ...not meaning to be a jerk here, but why? I am actually asking, not trying to be a jerk. The "runtime" node is apparently a thing, and I don't know how to find it--isn't that a question that can be asked and answered all on its own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this output from Visual Studio is misleading. The error itself (that you didn't include in your quote) is real and ontopic, but the proposed solution included in this error message does not apply to the platform you are working on.

In a classic Visual Studio (Windows, C#, etc) project you would have an `app.config` file. Part of this file is the configuration\runtime path, where you can set `binding redirects` to resolve versioning conflicts between assemblies.

[image: App.config file illustrating runtmie node]

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful answer.